# How to change the active node tree data block using python?

Tags: python, node-editor, animation-nodes

I'm using animation nodes add-on. How can I switch between the node tree data blocks using python (as shown in the picture below)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this(change "GeometryNodes")

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"].node_group =  bpy.data.node_groups["NodeTree.001"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)